# Oracle sql date query formats single-digit

Tags: sql, string, oracle, date, datetime

I need to retrieve dates from Oracle as Java SimpleDateFormat M/D/YYYY (for instance, Independence Dat would be 7/4/1776).  However, looking at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_commands_1029.htm#OLADM780
there appears only to be a way to retrieve MM/dd/yyyy (07/04/1776).

Are there any tricks to retrieve the date the original way?  I suppose I could play around with all sorts of if IF statements, and substrings, but that seems quite complicated.

That is to say

```
 select to_char(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') from dual    works
```

but

```
 select to_char(sysdate, 'M/D/YYYY') from dual    does not.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [format modifier `fm`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216) for this:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'fmMM/DD/YYYY') formated_date from dual
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d2f887cfc4ac609ab90b31947d6704fe)**:

```
 select to_char(date '1776-07-04', 'fmMM/DD/YYYY') formated_date from dual
```

```
| FORMATED_DATE |
| :------------ |
| 7/4/1776      |
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are your friend here:

```
WITH cteDate AS (SELECT TO_DATE('01/02/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS SOME_DATE FROM DUAL)
SELECT TO_CHAR(SOME_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS FORMATTED_SOME_DATE,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_CHAR(SOME_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), '0([0-9])/', '\1/') AS FIXED_DATE
  FROM cteDate
```

The above returns

```
FORMATTED_SOME_DATE    FIXED_DATE
02/01/2020             2/1/2020
```

To explain what's going on here:
The search expression `'0([0-9])/'` says "Look for a substring which starts with the '0' character, is followed by one character in the range '0' to '9', and is finished with a '/' character. Treat the character in the range '0' to '9' as a group'.

The replacement expressions `'\1/'` says "Replace what you found in the search string with the first grouped expression (there's only one), followed by a slash character'.

Comment: Yeeeaaahhhhh - @GMB's answer is really The Right Answer - but I'm leaving this up because it's a neat regular expression demo - and it *does* produce the right answer - but, really, use his answer in production code.

Comment: I am hoping to take a udemy course to learn more advanced oracle queries.  I can do complex ones but they are all with select and not with "with" statements and things, which I would like to learn.